# Unable to link Facebook and Google in Firebase Authentication

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to link Facebook and Google. So, the scenario is this:

I have already authenticated with Google. So, now I am logging in Facebook, having same email id which was used earlier with Google. So, I get the error of account Exists with a different credential. And, I did this:

```
func fetchUserInfo()
{
    Auth.auth().signInAndRetrieveData(with:FacebookAuthProvider.credential(withAccessToken: (FBSDKAccessToken.current().tokenString)!), completion: { (result, error) in

        if let error = AuthErrorCode.init(rawValue: error!._code)
        {
            switch error
            {
            case .accountExistsWithDifferentCredential :

                let credential = FacebookAuthProvider.credential(withAccessToken: (FBSDKAccessToken.current()?.tokenString)!)

                Auth.auth().currentUser?.linkAndRetrieveData(with: credential, completion: { (result, error) in

                    if let error = error
                    {
                        print("Unable to link Facebook Account", error.localizedDescription)
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        NavigationHelper.shared.moveToHome(fromVC: self)
                    }
                })
            default: break
            }
        }
        else
        {
            GeneralHelper.shared.keepLoggedIn()

            if let currentUser = Auth.auth().currentUser
            {
                print(currentUser.email!)
            }
            NavigationHelper.shared.moveToHome(fromVC: self)
        }
    })
}
```

Here Firebase Documentation says that we need to just link the `currentUser` and retrieve data. But, the issue I am facing is that the `currentUser` is always nil. So, how can I get the current user? I have already tried this months ago and then I was able to link Facebook, Google and Email. Do, I need to `signInAndRetrieve` the data from Google in order to get the `currentUser`?

Comment: You need to sign in the user first to Google and then link the Facebook credential to it so both accounts are merged. The next time the user can sign in with either.

Comment: Yeah, I already did that and linked the accounts.

Answer (score 0):

The Error "account Exists with a different credential" is because, by default, Firebase do not allow to use the same email address for two (or more) different Sing In methods. You need to enable this option.

1 - Go to **Authentication** > **Sign-in method**

[image: Authentication > Sign-in method]

2 - Scroll down to **Advanced: Multiple accounts per email address**

[image: Advanced]

3 - Change the option to **Allow creation of multiple accounts with the same email address**

[image]

FYI: You need to do whole login process for each Sign In method in your app. Each method has is own credentials.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I think the better way is to ask the user to login with the previous method and then silently linking their accounts. I think it is best to have one email and then link them with other credentials.

Comment: @Rob13 i do not think is a good idea to asume that the user email is the same for both platforms. Also, if you do not properly create a session there is no way to interact with the platform; Getting user real name, birthday, sharing a link, etc.